# How to handle future work over unmerged features in git flow?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I am using git flow - make feature branch, and merge them into develop, ... you know.

I made two features and made pull request to develop branch on GitHub. Call these as feature A and B.

Now I want to start work on latest commits - using A and B both. However, my code is not merged in GitHub because my reviewer didn't review it yet.

In this situation, how I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I refer to as "anticipating a branch".

Make a branch C off A. Now C has the content of A. Merge B into C. Now C has the content of A and B.

```
git checkout -b C A
git merge B
```

Tag that merge commit as where C started. This will be useful later.

```
git tag C-start
```

Do some work on C.

When A and B are merged into master, pull master. Now master has the content of A and B. Depending on how the PR and merge process went, that content is possibly different from what you merged into C. If we pushed C now, we'd resurrect the old A and B commits.

To avoids this, we rewrite just the C commits onto master. This is where the C-start tag is useful. We can use it to grab only the commits that were written to the C branch.

```
# Recommit from C-start to C onto master
git rebase --onto master C-start C
# Delete the C-start tag, we don't need it.
git tag -d C-start
```

Now just the commits on C have been rewritten on top of master. This ensures that C has the updated content of A and B which was merged into master.

Now submit C as a PR.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! I think the C-start idea is great.

Comment: But how would you go about creating a merge/pull request for C? I.e. if you are not allowed to do changes on master manually/by yourself.

Comment: @Rafael-WO You wait until A and B are merged before making a PR for C.

Comment: @Schwern but without rebasing onto master, right? Or can you make a PR with changes only starting from C-start?

Comment: @Rafael-WO Once A and B are merged into master, you rebase C onto master. Now C has the merged versions of A and B which are in master. Then you can make a PR for C. I've updated the answer to hopefully make the procedure more clear.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the update, I think now I understand it! I was thinking that rebasing onto master would somehow change master, but I guess it does not. After the rebase, one still needs to merge C into master (=accept PR).